# Get results of command from Cygwin in Batch

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file, cygwin

## The Problem

I'm a little new to Cygwin and I'm trying to run a shell script in Cygwin from Batch and get the return value. I've been searching around, and I tried using `C:\cygwin[64]\bin\bash[64].exe` and even messing with `C:\cygwin[64]\Cygwin.bat` but to no avail.

Basically, I just want to be able to, from batch, interact with bash (from Cygwin). Please excuse me if this seems trivial to you, as I am rather new to Cygwin. Anyways, I have yet to find a working online solution.

## Example Sudo Code:

```
cygwin-magic "echo shell-command"
#=> shell-command
```

## Some Stuff I've Tried

I found all of these things from a lengthy Google hunt. Nothing did what I wanted it to.

```
"C:\cygwin[64]\bin\base[64].exe" /cygdrive/c/users/<me>/desktop/tmp.sh
#=> ZWNobyAiaGVsbG8i

"C:\cygwin[64]\bin\base[64].exe" -d /cygdrive/c/users/<me>/desktop/tmp.sh
#=> y▒h/usr/bin/base[64]: invalid input

"C:\cygwin[64]\bin\base[64].exe" -d -i /cygdrive/c/users/<me>/desktop/tmp.sh
#=> y▒h▒▒e/usr/bin/base[64]: invalid input

"C:\cygwin[64]\bin\base[64].exe" -d -i "echo hello"
#=> /usr/bin/base[64]: echo hello: No such file or directory

# I kind of gave up on all of my other attempts and tried this because why not? Surprise surprise, it didn't work (not that I expected it to).
"C:\cygwin[64]\Cygwin.bat"
echo "hello"
```

### Contents of tmp.sh

Simply,

```
echo "hello"
```

## Purpose

The reason I want to do this from batch is that I want to interact with bash from another language through batch (on Windows). I've got my solution planned out in that third language, but it's just the batch-to-cygwin that's not working.

## Notes

- Windows 7 Home Premium x64
- Cygwin x64
- I wrote all `64`s in the code as `[64]` because I know 32-bit builds don't use that.
- If I missed something or my question's a little off (too broad, too specific, etc.), please comment and I'll change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you meant `"C:\cygwin[64]\bin\basH[64].exe"` not `"C:\cygwin[64]\bin\base[64].exe"`

Comment: **EDIT:** Yep, I made a stupid mistake. This changing it to `bash.exe` works!

Comment: It might not have been me but where I got it from, but whatever.

Comment: @FirstZero - not the case, it would seem... :)

Comment: Apologies - upvoted your answer and removed the incorrect comment.